# Android telecom/connection service: Open app from recent call history

Tags: android, android-connectionservice

I have been able to implement `ConnectionService` and `Android.Telecom` to receive an incoming call. I see the phone number/name of caller id in recent call in phone app. I want to open my app when tapped on any of that number/name which is associated with my app. When i tap on that, it shows "Choose sim for this call" with option to my network provider and also my app. When i tapped on my app, it doesn't open my app.

Basically i want to open my app when tapping on recent call -> phone/name. So how to achieve this?

Comment: Any update about it?

Comment: No, i was not able to find solution. I changed my implementation with broadcast receiver and custom notification to mimic the system call.